# Time complexity of nested loops

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, complexity-theory, time-complexity

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i = i ∗ 2){
     for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
         if(i == j){
            for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){
               // Do something elementary
            }
         }else{
            // Do another elementary thing
         }
     }
 }
```

I am doing some exercise, and can someone please help me to figure out the Θ of the above algorithm? I understand that if it was just the two outer nested loops, the time complexity should be Θ(nlogn). But I don't know how to treat the if-else statement. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint 1: how many times does `i == j` in this loop? Hint 2: can you lift the innermost loop out of the middle one so the program becomes easier to analyze?

Comment: Thanks. I have been thinking about how many times does i==j, but no conclusion..

Comment: @matheburg It is usually assumed that comparison and branching take O(1) time.

Comment: @Iarsman Sorry - I totally overlooked the inner inner loop! :D so just forget about my stupid comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You execute the outer loop `log(n)` times, because you double the value for i every time

Then you execute the inner loop `n` times, and the last inner loop inf the if statement you execute once (if `i == j` holds) `n` times, this the whole inner loop needs `n + n` steps each time.

This gives you an upper bound of `O(2n log(n))` and since constants do not change the asymptotic complexity the runtime is bounded by `O(n log(n))`

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i = i ∗ 2){                    ----------
 for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){            ----------             |
     if(i == j){                                  |            |
        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){     ----      |            |
           // Do something elementary       | (n  | + n )      | * log(n)
        }                               ----      |            |
     }else{                                       |            |
        // Do another elementary thing            |            |
     }                                  ----------             |
 }                                                             |
}                                                              |
                                                   ------------
```

Note that the most inner loop is executed only once per second most inner loop (!) and since the second most inner loop gets executed `log n` times (with having `n` steps) we have to add the `n` times for the most inner loop to the runtime of the second most inner loop and then multiply it with the overall time the seondmost inner loop is executed

Comment: How come the most inner loop got executed n times? I don't know how many times it should run but I guess i==j won't happen for n times?

Comment: that's right it only gets executet once, but the loop itself has n steps

Comment: say for example when n=16, the most inner loop executes when i=j=2,4 and 16, that's not once but 3 times right?

Comment: @stillAFanOfTheSimpsons Actually for n=16, i==j for 1,2,4,8, and for a general n, i==j for O(log(n)) values of i.

Comment: during the execution of j-loop, condition i==j is true only once, and at that time a n-times loop is executed. So for the j-loop there is n-1 iterations (elementary constant time thing) + 1 that runs a n-loop. Then roughly 2n.

Comment: Thanks @wastl! It makes much more sense now. I see why you say that the most inner loop execute only once per second most inner loop, is that why we add n to the runtime of second most inner loop, instead of multiplying (n*n)? Also for the else statement, since it doesn't affect the runtime of the second most inner loop, so we don't need to worry about it?

Comment: ah thanks @Jean-BaptisteYunès! I think I get why it's nlogn now!